# How to set a new field in a firestore database by looking at the UID

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I'm trying to add a profilePicturePath to a firebase database record, but I can't seem to add it to an existing record in the database.

my current code is

```
let db = Firestore.firestore();
            
db.collection("users").document(user?.uid ?? "").setData(["profilePictureURL" : uploadRef.fullPath])
```

The user id stored locally is a field in the firebase record.

the profilePicutreURL does not exist as a field in the firebase record at the point im trying to insert. (not even sure if that matters)

in sudocode id imagine its something like

```
database.getCollection("Users").getRecordWithFieldValue("uid" : "localUserObject.uid").setField("profilePicture" : uploadRef.fullPath"
```

Really sorry if this is a stupid question, very new to IOS and firebase.

any help or guidance on this problem, or any of my other shoddy code would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you need to use something like this. First a query will return an optional QuerySnapshot which you need to get the docs from and iterate through them to get the ID. There should only be one UID but I don't know how you set this up. From there you have a docID which you can use within a DocumentReference using the updateData method not setData.

```
 func getUserDocIDWith(uid: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let usersRef = db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
        
        usersRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                let docs = snapshot!.documents
                for each in docs {
                    completion(each.documentID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func updateUserWith(path: String) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    
    getUserDocIDWith(uid: uid) { docID in
        let usersRef = db.collection("users").document(docID)
        usersRef.updateData(["profilePictureURL" : path])
    }
}

updateUserWith(path: uploadRef.fullPath)
```

Comment: That looks exactly like what i need, one last really stupid question, i'm not sure how i actually call this method. The completion @escaping stuff is completely new to me.

    let userDocId = Utilities.getUserDocIDWith(uid: user?.uid!, ?????)
                
   db.collection("users").document(userDocId).setData(["profilePictureURL" : uploadRef.fullPath])

Comment: I updated it. If you are updating your users often which you would be you should re-think how you have created these docs in the first place.

Comment: Awesome, it's working perfectly now. Thanks man for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

let db = Firestore.firestore()
let userRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)

userRef.setData(["profilePictureURL" : uploadRef.fullPath])
```

Comment: Thats awesome, thanks, so the db.collection("users").document(uid). Is that getting that record by the uid field, or by the record name of that users? See the image i've added, is it the 'fgrfm' id or is it the 'Yfysl' value of the field? I'm wondering because i'll be wanting to get the record by the id in the uid field in the record for users that aren't the current user later.

Comment: Its does two things. You have users you have authenticated right. Each user is saved with an Identifier (an email) and a UID. Using setData this way creates a new Doc within the User's collection with the document ID of their UID. It's the "fgrfm" If you wanted you could add their UID as a field within the doc so it's in both places.

Comment: Ah so i tried that and its creating a new record as you said, i just want it to update the existing user record. And get that record from the uid field on the record

Comment: Correct, i only know the UID field within the record that i want to update